# create resharper naming convention based on data type of the variable

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

I am trying to create a custom naming convention rule in resharper based on the data type of the variable. I want to create a rule that would check the data type of the variable and would recomend matching prefix. Is this even possible.

Forexample for these local variables:

```
Dim strName As String
Dim intAge As Integer
Dim strGender As Boolean
```

In this case resharper rule should underline strGender since type is Boolean and prefix is str instead of bln. It would be nice if it would suggest blnGender for a new variable name similarly for variables with int prefix for Integer type, str for string, obj for object.

I am not worried about unknown types at compile time. I am working with ReSharper8

Comment: Nope. We just went with defaults